# PHP AWS Host Key verification failed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 instance.  I am trying to connect to the instance from a local machine using php.  I have already installed `awscli`, `aws-sdk-php`, configured aws cli with access keys and secret keys.  Besides, I have created a `config.php` to include the access keys and secret keys.  I am using a .pem file to connect to the ec2 instance.  The .pem file has 400 permission and is owned by www-data:www-data and it is residing inside /var/www/html folder.

Through a php script I am initiating the instance.  The ec2 instance gets initiated.  As a next step, I am trying to run a bash script through PHP.  The code for the same is as follows:

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@$ipaddress "bash /home/ubuntu/checkWorkingDir.sh $dirName"
```

While the EC2 gets started by php, the program `gets stuck here` and I am getting a message

`Host Key Verification Failed`.

I am able to log into EC2 through ssh manually by using the same .pem file from a different folder using:

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@ip_address -- this is working
```

the pem file in the /var/www/html folder lists like this:

```
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 1692 Jan 10 16:39 mypem.pem
```

I have created a same set up in my laptop and everything works fine.  In what all other ways I could read this problem of `Host key verification failed` message.

Comment: When you call the pem file in the ssh command, are you giving it the full path to the pem? (i.e.,   ssh -i ~/.ssh/mypem.pem ubuntu@ipaddress "bash /home/ubuntu/checkWorkingDir.sh $dirName" )    Or you can create an ssh config file with the connection details.